# Ubuntu 22.04 does not remember MFA in my microsoft teams account

Tags: authentication, microsoft

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, and every time I connect to my teams account it asks me to do the double factor authentication (MFA). From the admin side, it is supposed to remember the MFA for 90 days and in windows it works ok.
Also it is not a browser problem cause I tried in several and I'm always having the same problem, so it's a ubuntu thingy...

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest this is something you may want to address with the makers of the app.

Comment: Makers of the app is Microsoft...